# HTML Status 405 on api call

Tags: php, curl

I Want to call the api in plain php but when I use file_get_contents,CURL,get_header, i have checked with my web server everithing is enabled.(openssl,extension=php_openssl.dll)

I want to know why this is not running?

**Using file_get_contents**

```
<?php
    $username = 'ram@demo.com';
    $password = 'newnew';
    $medium = 'WEB';
    $json = file_get_contents("http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/auth/getAuthToken?namespaceCode=demo&username=ram@demo.com&password=newnew&devicemedium=WEB");
    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    echo $array;
    echo $array['status']; // status
    echo $array['datetime']; // date time
    echo $array['data']['authToken']; // auth token
    echo $array['data']['role']['code']; // code
?>
```

**output:**
file_get_contents(http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/auth/getAuthToken?namespaceCode=demo&username=ram%40demo.com&password=newnew&devicemedium=WEB): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed in /home/vkacadem/public_html/api/index.php on line 5.

**using crul:**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/auth/getAuthToken?namespaceCode=demo&username=$username&password=$password&devicemedium=$medium");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
**0/p: no response?**
```

my API is waiting calls through GET method.

Comment: You are using HTTP. why are you checking about openssl ?

Comment: if don't mind can you tell me when do you want to use openssl Just for this task I have searched everything in google. I am always ensure with stackteam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to POST the data. Add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST);
```

before sending the request.

Suggestion: if you're using Chrome, install the Postman extension. Will allow you to easily debug such problems.

Comment: Thank so much I got this {"status":1,"datetime":"2014-10-27 16:00:24","data":{"authToken":"11656053df210024257eed0ee8373e00e41c025a","role":{"code":"USER","name":"User","activeFlag":1}}} after this shall i want to include json_decode for showing my data? what i have to do next to show the data

Comment: json_decode will return an iterable object, so you can either print_r of use foreach to iterate over it, or just print out the information you're interested in. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for more details. Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);

Answer (score 0):

These are headers your API (http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/auth/getAuthToken?namespaceCode=demo&username=ram%40demo.com&password=newnew&devicemedium=WEB) returns:

    `Response Headers
    Allow:POST
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:0
    Date:Mon, 27 Oct 2014 10:33:02 GMT
    Server:nginx/1.4.4`

This resource allows only POST method, so you need to use POST for this request.

Comment: Thank you so much for valuable answer,if I understood correctly means I need to change the form action <form id='prt_tick' name="prt_tick" method="get" action="search/print-ticket" onsubmit="return false"> method="get" to post